# printf equivalent of cout statement (strings, and multiple variables in same statement)

Tags: c

I am looking for the `printf` (`C`) equivalent of this `C++` output statement (`cout`):

```
cout << "Indices and values: " << i << " " << j << ":" <<A_ii <<" "<< A_jj << endl;
```

Here `i`, `j` are integers and `A_ii`, `Ajj` are decimals. Presently, I am trying this, but it doesn't seem to give the desired output in `C`.

`printf("\nIndices and values: %d and %d : %d %d", i, j, A_ii, A_jj);`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's wrong? Except the fact you are appending the newline in the beginning instead of the end.

Comment: You say you're not getting the desired output, but haven't told us exactly what that is, nor what you're currently getting.

Comment: What's a decimal? A floating point number perhaps? Put together a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows all of the variable declarations.

Comment: I see a lot of differences just by reading it. You're obviously not printing "and" in your `cout` version, but you are in your `printf` version. Your `printf` version outputs a new line first, which your `cout` version doesn't do. If `A_ii` and `A_jj` are 
"decimals" I assume you mean some kind of floating point? So the `%d` specifiers in the `printf` format are wrong (they're for integers). Your `printf` version puts spaces around `:` but your `cout` version does not. Maybe you just need to go through your `printf` format more carefully.

Comment: if by decimal you mean they're doubles you should put `%f` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it right, you are just using the int `%d` format token for your decimals.  Try `%f` instead.

```
printf("\nIndices and values: %d and %d : %f %f", i, j, A_ii, A_jj);
```